# Парсинг строк с помощью php

Tags: php, парсер

Здравствуйте, имеется подобные бинарные ascii строки:

```
key1/data/key2/data/key3/data
```

Как из такой вот строки сделать массив вида `['key' => 'data']` и как можно быстрее по скорости бо обрабатывается в цикле много таких строк.

Comment: Какая версия php ?

Comment: split("/"), проход по полученному массиву и занесение данных из него в целевой массив. Четные элементы - ключи, нечетные - их значения.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, ф-ция `split` считается устаревшей с php 5.3.0. Вы, видимо, имели в виду `explode` ;-)

Comment: Ну я не настоящий PHP программист, переменную с долларом на улице нашел! :-) explode нынче используется для этих целей?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Если по регексу, то preg_split(),  по фиксированной строке - explode. В данном случае ее достаточно, а она сильно быстрее, соответственно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$str = 'key1/data/key2/data/key3/data';

$a = explode('/', $str);

$new = array();
foreach(array_chunk($a, 2) as $i) {
  $new[$i[0]] = $i[1];
}

print_r($new);
```

Comment: Также можно сделать с помощью regexp